# How to choose the template dynamically with fluidpages

Tags: typo3

I was using `fluidpages` for template building, and would like to choose the template dynamically based on a field in the fe_users table. For example, most people will see the `EXT:default` template by default, while some will see `EXT:advanced` template instead, as they are marked as special.

I tried

```
plugin.tx_template {
    view {
        templateRootPaths {
            0 = EXT:default/Resources/Private/Templates/
            10 {
                data = TSFE:fe_user|user|template
                wrap = EXT: | /Resources/Private/Templates/
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it seems the TS is not parsed and is used directly by `fluid`, therefore failed.

Any idea or hint is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this may be possible. But i can't see an obvious way on how to override the chosen template in the page properties.

To my knowledge, you are required to select a template in the page record.

If you find a possibility to override that one, you could use a TS Setup like this:

EXT:template_package/Configuration/TypoScript/constants.txt:

```
plugin.tx_templatepackage {
    view {
        templateRootPaths.default = EXT:template_package/Resources/Private/Templates/
        partialRootPaths.default = EXT:template_package/Resources/Private/Partials/
        layoutRootPaths.default = EXT:template_package/Resources/Private/Layouts/
    }
}
```

EXT:template_package/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.txt:

```
plugin.tx_templatepackage {
    view {
        templateRootPaths.default = {$plugin.tx_templatepackage.view.templateRootPaths.default}
        partialRootPaths.default = {$plugin.tx_templatepackage.view.partialRootPaths.default}
        layoutRootPaths.default = {$plugin.tx_templatepackage.view.layoutRootPaths.default}
    }
}
```

Above part will setup your global paths.
After that, you'll define your sub packages for templates.

EXT:template_package/Configuration/TypoScript/Basic/setup.txt

```
plugin.tx_templatepackage {
    view {
        templateRootPaths.10 = {$plugin.tx_templatepackage.view.templateRootPaths.0}Basic/
        partialRootPaths.10 = {$plugin.tx_templatepackage.view.partialRootPaths.0}Basic/
        layoutRootPaths.10 = {$plugin.tx_templatepackage.view.layoutRootPaths.0}Basic/
    }
}
```

And

EXT:template_package/Configuration/TypoScript/Advanced/setup.txt

```
plugin.tx_templatepackage {
    view {
        templateRootPaths.20 = {$plugin.tx_templatepackage.view.templateRootPaths.0}Advanced/
        partialRootPaths.20 = {$plugin.tx_templatepackage.view.partialRootPaths.0}Advanced/
        layoutRootPaths.20 = {$plugin.tx_templatepackage.view.layoutRootPaths.0}Advanced/
    }
}
```

Of course you should make them available within TYPO3:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addStaticFile($_EXTKEY, 'Configuration/TypoScript', 'Template Package: Base');
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addStaticFile($_EXTKEY, 'Configuration/TypoScript/Basic', 'Template Package: Basic');
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addStaticFile($_EXTKEY, 'Configuration/TypoScript/Advanced', 'Template Package: Advanced');
```

After all of that, you could override a value — IDK which one — via:

```
[usergroup = group1-uid]
// override option, which defines the default template
[usergroup = group2-uid]
// override option, which defines the default template
```

Sorry I can't help you out any further. I tried to dig deeper into EXT:flux and EXT:fluidpages. But i can't see that option.

Comment: Thank you Andy. Yes, I think maybe configure each template with the TS is the only way for now.